# Coding Challenge "ArithGeoII" why isn't function working?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

**Here is the challenge:**

Using the JavaScript language, have the function ArithGeoII(arr) take the array of numbers stored in arr and return the string "Arithmetic" if the sequence follows an arithmetic pattern or return "Geometric" if it follows a geometric pattern. If the sequence doesn't follow either pattern return "neither". An arithmetic sequence is one where the difference between each of the numbers is consistent, where as in a geometric sequence, each term after the first is multiplied by some constant or common ratio. Arithmetic example: [2, 4, 6, 8] and Geometric example: [2, 6, 18, 54].

**Here is my solution:**

```
function arithGeoII(arr) {
var x = "none of the above";
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ((arr[i + 1]) - (arr[i])) === ((arr[i + 2]) - (arr[i + 1])) {
        x = "arithmetic";
    } else if ((arr[i + 1]) / (arr[i])) === ((arr[i + 2]) / (arr[i + 1])) {
        x = "geometric";
    } 
  }
  return x;
}
```

I've been able to find several solutions to this that make sense but I'm curious why mine isn't working? I'm obviously a beginner (so the answer might seem obvious to most), but I really appreciate any help!

Comment: the problem is that the iteration will work for the first and second value but not the third because when you use this `arr[1+2]` there wont be a number as it will be higher than the set in the array. Also per each iteration you are overwriting `x`, which i doubt is what you want to do

Comment: You must handle exception in your code as well. You are must likely to get index-out-of-range with your code. make multi dimenssion array which take object can hold 4 items instead like: 
var a = [];

a[0] = [1,2,3,4]; 
a[1] = [4,5,6,7];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, once a condition fails somewhere, you must exit the loop immediately.

Otherwise, you are only checking the last numbers.

For example, your code will say that `[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2]` is an arithmetic sequence because `1-0 === 2-1`. But it isn't, because the condition `arr[i+1]-arr[i] === arr[i+2]-arr[i+1]` does not hold everywhere.

Some working examples:

```js
function arith(arr) {
  for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i-1] - arr[i-2] !== arr[i] - arr[i-1])
      return false;
  return true;
}
function geom(arr) {
  for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; ++i)
    if (arr[i-1] / arr[i-2] !== arr[i] / arr[i-1])
      return false;
  return true;
}
function arithGeoII(arr) {
  var a = arith(arr), g = geom(arr);
  if(a && g) return "both";
  if(a) return "aritmetic";
  if(g) return "geometric";
  return "none";
}
```

```js
function arithGeoII(arr) {
  var arit = true, geom = true;
  for (var i = 2; i < arr.length && (arit || geom); ++i) {
    if (arit && arr[i-1] - arr[i-2] !== arr[i] - arr[i-1])
      arit = false;
    if (geom && arr[i-1] / arr[i-2] !== arr[i] / arr[i-1])
      geom = false;
  }
  if(arit && geom) return "both";
  if(arit) return "aritmetic";
  if(geom) return "geometric";
  return "none";
}
```

Comment: The problem is more than that, and your solution is incorrect. What do you think it will return for [0,1,2,4]?

Comment: @Gildor I explained the main problem (there are syntax errors too). My solution can't be wrong because I didn't include any (I can if you want). `[0,1,2,4]` is neither arithmetic nor geometric, because `2-1 !== 4-2` and `1/0 !== 2/1`.

Comment: Well, it depends on how to understand `once a condition fails somewhere`. I got what you say, but it's unclear in my opinion, because there are a few ways to "fail" the condition.

Comment: Thanks - your solution & examples help lot. I'm still curious why [2, 4, 8, 16, 200] returns "Geometric" though... ps - voted up but it doesn't change the public score lol

Comment: @LukeSchunk `[2, 4, 8, 16, 200]` produces `"none"` with both my examples.

Comment: @LukeSchunk Ah, that's because it detects `2, 4, 8, 16` is geometric. Then it detects `8, 16, 200` is neither arithmetic nor geometric, but `x` is not updated.

Comment: @Oriol goths thanks. Last question promise: when you say if(arit && geom) return "arithmetic"; is that shorthand for coding if(arit && geom) are true return "arithmetic";? is true sort of like a 'default' in JavaScript booleans?

Comment: @LukeSchunk That code checks if the sequence is both arithmetic and geometric (e.g. `[]`, `[1,2]`, `[1,1,1,1,1,1]`), and then returns `"both"`. The expression `a && b` will return a truthy value if all operands are truthy, or a falsy value if at least one operand is falsy.